# zip function to store multiple outputs for a return statement

Tags: python, list, while-loop, zip, append

```
def somefunction():
    outputs = []
    a = 0
    while a < 100:
        if a%2 == 0:
            b = 2*a + 1
            outputs.append(list(zip(a,b)))
        a += 1
    return outputs
```

The above code is not what i'm using exactly but produces the same error, why does the above code return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration
```

Is this a particularly efficient way of returning all the items within a function as one? If not, what is a better method?

Comment: zip expects two lists ... its unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Exactly what do you want the returned value to be?  If you want a list of 2-tuples, is something wrong with `outputs.append((a, b))`?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do? Possibly, are you trying to return multiple values? If so, it's perfectly acceptable to return multiple values in Python.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make your function a generator - look up [`yield`](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).

Comment: I am trying to group all the returns from the loop into one list but keep both a and b related to eachother. But in my original function I have more than 2 items.

Comment: Well that seems like a perfect substitution, thanks Tim, thanks for all the responses all.

Answer (score 0):

It returns that error because of its exact error message; that is, the [zip](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) arguments must support iteration. You just have two numbers that you are trying to "store together". In that case, I'm assuming what you are looking for is the [tuple](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-tuple) data type. Either that or "put them together" with the list data type you already have. The zip is entirely unnecessary. I would suggest reading more about [Python's built-in types](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Just get a list of tuples!! (or list if you prefer, but since you can't change tuples and you want to return all the outputs, tuples make more sense)

```
def somefunction():
    outputs = []
    a = 0
    while a < 100:
        if a%2 == 0:
            b = 2*a + 1
            tup = (a,b)
            outputs.append(tup)
        a += 1
    return outputs
```

There is no need to use `zip` here, zip is for joining two lists together, you only have two integers so you can store them in a tuple and then `append` the tuple to `outputs`

## when zip would work for this

Zip would work if you stored all `a`s in `a_list` and all `b`s in `b_list`. Then you could do:

```
outputs.append(zip(a_list,b_list))
```

this is unnecessary because you can just `append` `a` and `b` together in a tuple to `output` just like my example. But that is how it would be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use list comprehension in this case:

```
def f():
    return [(x, 2*x + 1) for x in range(100) if x%2 == 0]
```